# Using partial_fit with Scikit Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do you call `partial_fit()` on a scikit-learn classifier wrapped inside a [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)()?

I'm trying to build an incrementally trainable text classifier using `SGDClassifier` like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), non_negative=True)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier())),
])
```

but I get an `AttributeError` trying to call `classifier.partial_fit(x,y)`.

It supports `fit()`, so I don't see why `partial_fit()` isn't available. Would it be possible to introspect the pipeline, call the data transformers, and then directly call `partial_fit()` on my classifier?

Comment: Did you eventually come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 17):

Here is what I'm doing - where 'mapper' and 'clf' are the 2 steps in my Pipeline obj.

```
def partial_pipe_fit(pipeline_obj, df):
    X = pipeline_obj.named_steps['mapper'].fit_transform(df)
    Y = df['class']
    pipeline_obj.named_steps['clf'].partial_fit(X,Y)
```

You probably want to keep track of performance as you keep adjusting/updating your classifier - but that is a secondary point

so more specifically - the original pipeline(s) were constructed as follows

```
to_vect = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(min_df=2, max_df=.9, ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 100)),
                            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())])
full_mapper = DataFrameMapper([
            ('norm_text', to_vect),
            ('norm_fname', to_vect), ])

full_pipe = Pipeline([('mapper', full_mapper), ('clf', SGDClassifier(n_iter=15, warm_start=True,
                                                                n_jobs=-1, random_state=self.random_state))])
```

google DataFrameMapper to learn more about it - but here it just enables a transformation step that plays nice with pandas

Answer (score 9):

Pipeline does not use `partial_fit`, hence does not expose it. We would probably need a dedicated pipelining scheme for out-of-core computation but that also depends on the capabilities of the previous models.

In particular in this case you would probably want to do several passes over your data, one to fit each stage of the pipeline and then to transform the dataset to fit the next one, except for the first stage which is stateless, hence does not fit parameters from the data.

In the mean time it's probably easier to roll your own wrapper code tailored to your needs.

Comment: Can you recommend how I might roll my own? I tried using the pipeline's transform() method, and then extracting the classifier and feeding the transformed data to it's partial_fit(), but I get an error about the tdf vector being undefined.

Comment: Read the [source code of the Pipeline class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/pipeline.py#L26) and [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html). Then read the documentation for [text feature extraction and the hashing trick](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#vectorizing-a-large-text-corpus-with-the-hashing-trick) to make sure you fully understand the issue with stateful feature extraction. The implementation will depend on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: In particular if you use stateful transformers as `TfidfTransformer` you will need to do several passes on your data.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is 8 years old it is still very relevant and has not been updated for quite a time now.

As the matter of fact, there is now a nice package created by Vincent Warmerdam called `tokenwiser`.

It is used for NLP stuff mostly to fit within the `sklearn` infrastructure. However, there is the main building block that can be used even for not NLP tasks.

The package has `PartialPipeline`  boiler plate and [Documentantation](https://koaning.github.io/tokenwiser/api/pipeline.html).

Example here:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer

from tokenwiser.textprep import Cleaner, Identity, HyphenTextPrep
from tokenwiser.pipeline import PartialPipeline, PartialFeatureUnion

pipe = PartialPipeline([
    ("clean", Cleaner()),
    ("union", PartialFeatureUnion([
        ("full_text_pipe", PartialPipeline([
            ("identity", Identity()),
            ("hash1", HashingVectorizer()),
        ])),
        ("hyphen_pipe", PartialPipeline([
            ("hyphen", HyphenTextPrep()),
            ("hash2", HashingVectorizer()),
        ]))
    ])),
    ("clf", SGDClassifier())
])

X = [
    "i really like this post",
    "thanks for that comment",
    "i enjoy this friendly forum",
    "this is a bad post",
    "i dislike this article",
    "this is not well written"
]

y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

for loop in range(3):
    pipe.partial_fit(X, y, classes=[0, 1])
```

I can imagine this template working even for non-NLP-related stuff. Hope someone will find this super usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I also propose my basic implementation of utilizing partial_fit within a sklearn pipeline.

We just need to use a model that allows for partial fit (e.g. SGDregressor, xgboost, etc) and create own sklearn compatible classes

(Huge KUDOS to VIncent Warmerdam who started this in his [TOKENWISER](https://koaning.github.io/tokenwiser/guide/sklearn.html#partial-fit) project)

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklego.preprocessing import PatsyTransformer

class xgboost_partial_trainer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    allows for incremental training od xgboost model within a sklean pipeline
    """

    def __init__(self, training_params: dict = None):

        self.training_params = training_params
        self.trained_model = None
        self._first_call = True
        self.evals_result = {}
        self.iter_number = 1
        self._X_train, self._X_test, self._y_train, self._y_test = (
            None,
            None,
            None,
            None,
        )

    def partial_fit(self, X, y=None, classes=None, **fit_params):

        print(f"firts run: {self._first_call}, n_iter = {self.iter_number}")
        self.iter_number += 1

        if self._first_call:

            # Select random subset of data and store within the model (for error loss over time)
            self._X_train, self._X_test, self._y_train, self._y_test = train_test_split(
                X, y, test_size=0.6, random_state=1
            )

            self._xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(self._X_train, label=self._y_train)
            self._xg_test = xgb.DMatrix(self._X_test, label=self._y_test)

            # validations set to watch performance - same testing data, changebla training data
            self.watchlist = [
                (self._xg_train, "train_batch"),
                (self._xg_test, "eval_fixed"),
            ]

            # Trainig Part Itself
            self.trained_model = xgb.train(
                params=self.training_params,
                dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X, y),
                xgb_model=self.trained_model,
                evals=self.watchlist,
            )

            # Swich outside firts batch
            self._first_call = False

        else:
            self._xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(X, y)
            self.watchlist = [
                (self._xg_train, "train_batch"),
                (self._xg_test, "eval_fixed"),
            ]

            self.trained_model = xgb.train(
                params=self.training_params,
                dtrain=self._xg_train,
                xgb_model=self.trained_model,
                evals=self.watchlist,
            )
        #             self._predicted_y = self.trained_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(self._X_test))
        #             print(f"mean_squared_error = {mean_squared_error(self._y_test, self._predicted_y, squared = False)}")

        return self

    def predict(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self.trained_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))

    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self.trained_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(X))

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self


class PartialPipeline(Pipeline):
    """
    Utility function to generate a `PartialPipeline`

    Arguments:
        steps: a collection of text-transformers
    """

    def partial_fit(self, X, y=None, classes=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Fits the components, but allow for batches.
        """

        #         print(f"there are partial steps {self.steps_partial}")

        for _, step in self.steps:
            if hasattr(step, "partial_fit"):
                step.partial_fit(X, y, **kwargs)

            elif hasattr(step, "fit_transform"):
                X = step.fit_transform(X)

            elif hasattr(step, "transform"):
                X = step.transform(X)

            elif hasattr(step, "fit"):
                X = step.fit(X)

        return self
```

Once we have these sklearn classes we may utilize the `Pipeline`:

```
my_pipeline = PartialPipeline([
("patsy", PatsyTransformer(FORMULA2)),
("xgboost_model", xgboost_partial_trainer(training_params=params)),
])

df_chunked = pd.read_csv(your_date, chunksize=5_000)

for df in df_chunked:
    my_pipeline.partial_fit(df, y=df["speed"])
```

Please, provide me with feedback and code cleaning suggestions. I am fully aware that this is not perfect. However, as a nice prototype - not too bad!