# Sklearn: Suggest alternative of partial_fit with scikit Pipelines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I want to classify some data and the data set is so huge. As data is so huge I will like to go for partial_fit but the pipelines are not supporting in it. So is there some way around by which I can complete this task.

[this question is opposite of my requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931865/using-partial-fit-with-scikit-pipeline)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using partial\_fit with Scikit Pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931865/using-partial-fit-with-scikit-pipeline)

Comment: No in this case i am asking for partial_fit alternative because for huge dataset i have to go through partial fit for sure.

Comment: I think that the only possible solution for this - write your own code. You should transform your dataset, and if it's huge - apply partial_fit by chunks and save it into some storage again. Then load it by chunks and learn estimators with partial_fit.